# Why div doesn't fit its height based on nested span height

Tags: html, css

I've just found a problem I just can't understand. Why this div is bigger than the nested span? I thought that div fit its height to its content.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>This is test label</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the parent element of the div? Also I can't see where the size of the span is specified other than the font size.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when the font is shrinking, the parent div is preserving the line-height it was initially loaded with, set the line-height on the div same as the font-size and add an extra pixel and align the span vertically top, it will do the trick:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 10px;
  }

span {
    font-size: 9px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>This is test label</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table-cell` to the `span` tag. There is no such behavior for a `div` in which it automatically fits perfectly to its child's contents.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>This is test label</span>
</div>
```

If you want the `div`'s width to match the `span`'s width also, add `display: table-cell` to the div tag.

Comment: Can you explain why adding 'display: table-cell' to the span forces the outer div height match that span?

Comment: @Behnil display: table-cell doesn't force the outer div to match the span's height, but rather the span to match the div's height. display: table-cell makes the span behave like a td tag, which fills the div's height because your markup only has one cell. If a table has only one cell, than that cell will fill the table's height, regardless of how long the table (div) is.

Comment: But when you run my snippet and your snippet, you can see the span height is the same. On the other side the div gets smaller in your example. I'm really confused.